# Can be add multiple new columns in single statement in room db migration?

Tags: android, mysql, kotlin, android-room

I want to add multiple columns, in a single statement, in Room database Migration.

For Example:

`MySQL>Alter Table Student ADD(Address Varchar(25), Phone INT, Email Varchar(20));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible and sqlite itself doesn't allow it.
You have to  fire multiple alter queries to add each column per query.

Comment: SQL supports it https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-add-column/ but I guess, Android Rooms doesn't support it for now.